# Ubuntu 20.04 sennheiser GSP 350 sound and microphone issues

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, headset

I just bought a Sennheiser GSP 350 wired headset.
I plugged it in (USB) on my ubuntu 20.04 laptop and the sound worked perfectly, speaker-test even worked nicely with surround sound.

Then I started debugging why the mic did not work and changed settings in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (adding several types of options snd-hda-intel model=XXX). Also installed alsa-mixer-gui for hdajackretask.

Eventually nothing of the changes worked and I reset every change, except for deinstalling software.

Now my headset does not work correctly anymore and sounds horrible. When using speaker-test only the front-left and two sidechannels seem to work. Center and front right do not give a test sound.

Where do I start with fixing this?